# Elastic Beanstalk & Docker - EB CLI Does Not Work on Mac! BUG

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebcli

When I try and use elastic beanstalk from the command line (ie `eb create project`) I got the following error.

```
Select a platform version.
1) Docker 17.03.2-ce
2) Docker 1.12.6
3) Docker 1.11.2
4) Docker 1.9.1
5) Docker 1.7.1
6) Docker 1.6.2
7) Docker 1.5.0
(default is 1): 1
Note: Elastic Beanstalk now supports AWS CodeCommit; a fully-managed source control service. To learn more, see Docs: https://aws.amazon.com/codecommit/
Do you wish to continue with CodeCommit? (y/N) (default is n): n
Do you want to set up SSH for your instances?
(Y/n): y

Select a keypair.
1) patientplatypus
2) phoenixvuenewsly
3) [ Create new KeyPair ]
(default is 2): 1
patientplatypus:~/Documents/newsly_project:11:56:37$eb create newsly_project_production
ERROR: Platform Docker 17.03.2-ce does not appear to be valid
patientplatypus:~/Documents/newsly_project:11:57:44$docker --version
Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4
```

I thought the above seemed understandable enough, at first. I have version 17.09.0-ce of Docker, but I need version 17.03.2-ce. It would seem reasonable that AWS would be a few versions behind the latest version of Docker if nothing else than to double check system integration and security.

However, when it came time to find version 17.03.2-ce I found it almost impossible. https://github.com/moby/moby/releases points me to 17.03.02-ce as a direct link on the downloads page, which again downloads the wrong version. I tried downloading the link to the static binaries, however that was very confusing. This page https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/binaries/#next-steps says that in order to get the static binaries to compile I should run the command `sudo cp docker/docker /usr/local/bin/`, however nowhere in that static binary folder is there a folder labeled docker.

Meanwhile this page https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/release-notes/#docker-community-edition-17090-ce-mac32-2017-10-02-stable, goes from release *Docker Community Edition 17.03.1-ce-mac12, 2017-05-12 (stable)* to release *Docker Community Edition 17.06.0-ce-mac18, 2017-06-28 (stable)*. Not only does this skip the one release I need, but it seems to have versions that are *ahead* of the most recent release at https://github.com/moby/moby/releases.

I'm very very confused. It should not be as difficult as this to get the currently stable version of Docker that runs with AWS. Can someone let me know how to resolve this issue?

EDIT:

I spun up my Linux Mint 18 (Ubuntu 16.04) and installed docker to try and get this to work. As it happens linux ALSO installs version `Docker version 17.09.0-ce`, however this one works with the `1) Docker 17.03.2-ce` elastic beanstalk option. All the same commands on a linux environment running the same version of docker now run on eb cli. Therefore I am retitling this post as an EB CLI bug for mac. My question now is, where do I submit a bug report to AWS? I have searched for a github repository for them, but have not found it, and I think that most of their reporting through *aws.amazon.com* is for enterprise level customers.

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a bug in the EBCLI. Can you post on AWS forums? You might receive an explanation for your problem there.